# Is there a way to optimize this code so it doesn't overflow the stack?

Tags: recursion, optimization, rust, stack-overflow

I am working on the third Project Euler problem:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", p3());
}

fn p3() -> u64 {
    let divs = divisors(1, 600851475143, vec![]);
    let mut max = 0;
    for x in divs {
        if prime(x, 0, false) && x > max {
            max = x
        }
    }
    max
}

fn divisors(i: u64, n: u64, div: Vec<u64>) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut temp = div;
    if i * i > n {
        temp
    } else {
        if n % i == 0 {
            temp.push(i);
            temp.push(n / i);
        }
        divisors(i + 2, n, temp)
    }
}

fn prime(n: u64, i: u64, skip: bool) -> bool {
    if !skip {
        if n == 2 || n == 3 {
            true
        } else if n % 3 == 0 || n % 2 == 0 {
            false
        } else {
            prime(n, 5, true)
        }
    } else {
        if i * i > n {
            true
        } else if n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0 {
            false
        } else {
            prime(n, i + 6, true)
        }
    }
}
```

The value `600851475143` is the value that is at some point causing it to overflow. If I replace that with any value that is in the 10<sup>10</sup> order of magnitude or less, it returns an answer. While keeping it as a recursive solution, is there any way to either:

1. Increase the stack size?
2. Optimize my code so it doesn't return a `fatal runtime: stack overflow` error?

I know this can be done iteratively, but I'd prefer to not do that.

Comment: Sticking to recursion is nonsensical here. The calls are tail recursive, so it's trivial to make functions iterative, and then you have the guarantee that they use constant stack space, rather than relying on TCO (which is not guaranteed and indeed seems to not happen in this case). Writing everything in recursion doesn't mesh well with Rust and insisting on recursion over iteration will get you nothing but headaches.

Comment: The answer to "how to increase the stack size" is going to already exist on SO somewhere; it's the same stack as a C program so you can use `ulimit` or whatever is appropriate for your OS.

Answer (score 2):

A vector containing 600 * 10<sup>9</sup> `u64`s means you'll need 4.8 terabytes of RAM or swapspace.

I'm sure you don't need that for this problem, you're missing some knowledge of math here: scanning till the square root of the 600851475143 will be sufficient. You may also speed up the program by using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Project Euler is nice to sharpen your math skills, but it doesn't help you with any programming language in particular. For learning Rust I started with [Exercism](http://exercism.io/languages/rust).

Comment: This is a good set of optimizations, which really is the point of Project Euler. However, the reluctance of OP to change programming styles means that at best this simply delays the problem to a larger number.

Answer (score 2):

Performing some optimizations, such as going just up to the square root of the number when checking for its factors and for whether it's a prime, I've got:

```
fn is_prime(n: i64) -> bool {
    let float_input = n as f64;
    let upper_bound = float_input.sqrt() as i64;

    for x in 2..upper_bound + 1 {
        if n % x == 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

fn get_factors(n: i64) -> Vec<i64> {
    let mut factors: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();

    let float_input = n as f64;
    let upper_bound = float_input.sqrt() as i64;

    for x in 1..upper_bound + 1 {
        if n % x == 0 {
            factors.push(x);
            factors.push(n / x);
        }
    }
    factors
}

fn get_prime_factors(n: i64) -> Vec<i64> {
    get_factors(n)
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|&x| is_prime(x))
        .collect::<Vec<i64>>()
}

fn main() {
    if let Some(max) = get_prime_factors(600851475143).iter().max() {
        println!("{:?}", max);
    }
}
```

On my machine, this code runs very fast with no overflow.

```
./problem003  0.03s user 0.00s system 90% cpu 0.037 total
```

Comment: I'd probably write it [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d900d2e001cd1e38a31ebdc727341c2d&version=stable).

Comment: Are you sure there are no large composite numbers for which `(n as f64).sqrt() as i64` is smaller than the actual square root of `n`? (I couldn't find any, just curious if it's provable)

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want the iterative version:

First, make sure that you compile with optimizations (`rustc -O` or `cargo --release`). Without it there's no chance for TCO in Rust. Your `divisors` function is tail-recursive, but it seems that moving this `Vec` up and down the recursion stack is confusing enough for LLVM to miss that fact. We can help the compiler a little, by using just a reference here:

```
fn divisors(i: u64, n: u64, mut div: Vec<u64>) -> Vec<u64> {
    divisors_(i, n, &mut div);
    div
}

fn divisors_(i: u64, n: u64, div: &mut Vec<u64>) {
    if i * i > n {
    } else {
        if n % i == 0 {
            div.push(i);
            div.push(n / i);
        }
        divisors_(i + 2, n, div)
    }
}
```

On my machine that changes make the code no longer segfault.

---

If you want to increase the stack size anyway, you should run your function in a separate thread with increased stack size (using [`std::thread::Builder::stack_size`](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/thread/struct.Builder.html#method.stack_size))

---

Rust has reserved the `become` keyword for guaranteed tail recursion,
so maybe in the future you'll just need to add one keyword to your code to make it work.